# Django model with relationships

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, models

I know, questions of this kind have been asked at least a bunch of times here, but I am kind of starting with django and I am having a tough time to apply solutions from similar questions and just put this stuff together.

I think my model should have 3 classess:

```
class Guild(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Battle(models.Model):
    guild1 = models.ForeignKey(Guild, related_name="guild_one")
    guild2 = models.ForeignKey(Guild, related_name="guild_two")
    # tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament) ???

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ????
```

A `Battle` is a war between two `Guilds` and takes place during a `Tournament`. There can be many `Battles` in a `Tournament`. A `Guild` can participate in several `Tournaments`.

I want to be able to search by Guild (to see every Battle of theirs, from every Tournament they have taken part in), by Tournament to see what Battles have been played out plus I would like to have access through Tournament to see which Guilds have ever participated. Will the above code (plus the line I commeneted out) work, because I feel like maybe Tournament class should have reference to Battle?

Also, if you could give an example of a query that will take all Guilds' names that participated in a given Tournament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model `Battle` is a fine place for having the foreign key to a tournament, so you can remove the comment, although you should use the quotation marks for referencing to the `Tournament`, since it's declared after the `Battle`, i.e. `models.ForeignKey('Tournament')`.

To get all the participating guilds' names in a list format, use the [backwards relation objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) `guild_one` and `guild_two` of the `Guild` object, the [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and the [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). Like this:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> Guild.objects.filter(Q(guild_one__tournament=t) |\
... Q(guild_two__tournament=t)).values_list('name', flat=True)
[u'red', u'blue', u'green', u'black']
```

Assuming that `t` references to some `Tournament`.

Comment: Very sleek, thanks! I am also trying to get all Guilds names that has ever battled with a particular Guild. In other words all opponents of a Guild and the Guild itself. I coded this but I only get Guilds ids instead of names: `Battle.objects.filter(Q(guild1=g) | Q(guild2=g)).values_list('guild1', 'guild2').distinct()` . Could you make a suggestion please?